# SQL Server : Obtener registro según condiciona y fecha mínima

Tags: sql-server, sql, transact-sql

favor agradeceré su ayuda respecto a obtener el siguiente resultado en sql server :

Tabla Marcas :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla Mantenciones :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla deseada :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debo obtener según una marca su mantención mas próxima a su fecha de ingreso.

Agradeceré algún ejemplo o guía respecto a esto, gracias.

```
create table #marcas (id int, marca nvarchar(40), fecha_ingreso date)
create table #mantenciones (id int, marca nvarchar(40), fecha_mantencion date)
insert into #marcas values (1,'FIAT','2020-03-10'),(2,'FORD','2020-04-05'),(3,'MAZDA','2020-05-01');
insert into #mantenciones values (1,'FIAT','2020-03-15'),(2,'FIAT','2020-03-17'),(3,'FIAT','2020-03-20');
insert into #mantenciones values (4,'FORD','2020-04-20'),(5,'FORD','2020-04-07');
insert into #mantenciones values (6,'MAZDA','2020-05-01'),(7,'MAZDA','2020-05-02');

SELECT * FROM #marcas;
SELECT * FROM #mantenciones
SELECT m.id,m.marca,ma.id,ma.fecha_mantencion FROM #marcas m

CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
 FROM #mantenciones
         WHERE Marca = m.Marca
         AND fecha_mantencion >= m.fecha_ingreso
         ORDER BY fecha_mantencion) ma;

DROP TABLE #mantenciones
DROP TABLE #marcas
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que todo, un consejo. Si ya tienes una tabla "maestra" de marcas, deberías usar el `IdMarca` en la tabla `Mantenciones`, literalmente ése es el beneficio de tener la tabla maestra en primer lugar.

Si entiendo correctamente tu consulta, el siguiente código te debería servir:

```
SELECT m.IdMarca,
       m.Marca,
       ma.IdMantencion,
       ma.FechaMantencion
FROM dbo.Marcas m
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM dbo.Mantenciones
             WHERE Marca = m.Marca
             AND FechaMantencion >= m.FechaIngreso
             ORDER BY FechaMantencion) ma
;
```

Esto asumiento que si no hay una mantención para la marca correspondiente, igual entrega la marca, pero con `NULL` en los datos de mantención. Si no necesitas que aparezca el resultado puedes usar `CROSS APPLY` en vez de `OUTER APPLY`

Comment: Muchas gracias @Lamak, perfecto es lo necesitado, utilice CROSS APPLY. Agradecido amigo.

Comment: Hola @Lamak, buenas tardes. Consulta : Me esta tardando demasiado en hacer esta query y son pocos registros, estos usando Cross Apply, alguna otra forma que podría obtener el mismo resultado?? por favor.

Comment: Hola @Lamak por favor me ayudas, el Cross Apply se ha tornado muy pesado...